# Efficient Filtration of nested Object: Lodash or plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I am new to lodash. I have a javascript object as mentioned below. The purpose of this is to explore/learn efficient filter process of objects specially when data is huge and is nested too. I appreciate your guidance in this regard.

**JavaScript Object is:**

```
{
 "Bus-1": {
 "Seat1": {
   "Bookings": {
    "21032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Jon Doe"
    },
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 9:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "James"
    }
  },
  "Id": 1
},
"Seat2": {
  "Bookings": {
    "20032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Elijah"
    },
    "21032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Scott"
    }
  },
  "Id": 2
},
"Seat3": {
  "Bookings": {
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "22/03/2022 02:41 AM",
      "BookedBy": "Williams"
    }
  },
  "Id": 3
}
 },
 "Bus-2": {
 "Seat1": {
  "Bookings": {
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "22/03/2022 02:39 AM",
      "BookedBy": "Lucas"
    }
  },
  "Id": 1
    }
  }
}
```

From the above collection, the object hierarchy is as mentioned below in the image.

[image]

**What I have Tried So Far**

```
 loop...
 Object to array and then array filter function which further leads to filtration again and again
 Object to array and then lodash filter function which also cause nested filtration again and again in this case
```

**What I want to Achieve:**

So far what I have identified is *looping and filtration slow the process when there is huge data*.
I am looking for *an efficient method which return an object of all Bookings based on dates* as mentioned below so that I can further validated if user has booking for same day or not.

```
    "21032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Jon Doe"
    },
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 9:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "James"
    },
    "20032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Elijah"
    },
    "21032022": {
      "BookedAt": "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
      "BookedBy": "Scott"
    },
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "22/03/2022 02:41 AM",
      "BookedBy": "Williams"
    },
    "22032022": {
      "BookedAt": "22/03/2022 02:39 AM",
      "BookedBy": "Lucas"
    }
```

Regards,
Aqdas

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please don't post your object structure as an image, but as well formatted text. Also, your question is quite vague? Provide examples of input and corresponding expected output, and with which code you have tried, and what the problem is you encountered with your code.

Comment: Can you provide the input as plain text and an example of the expected output?

Comment: Please be more specific: Is the filter always on an attribute of Bookings, in this exact object model? Is there something that would let you avoid looking at all items? Are they sorted, are you only looking for a number of instances, ...?

Comment: @trincot - I hope the question makes better understanding now. Thanks

Comment: @dippas please see the question as I have updated

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza the question is updated

Comment: @TommyHansen I have updated question to make it more specific

Comment: @Aqdas what you want to achieve is not possible. Note that there are many collisions: entries with repeated keys. In an object each key must be unique. I suggest using a key format such as `1-1-21032022` where the first 2 numbers represent the bus and seat numbers

Comment: @LuísAlves thanks for getting back to me on this. I am also of the same opinion and that's why I thought I should post a question to know or take suggestions on what could be the best and efficient approach in such cases when data is huge and is nested too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```js
const result = _.assign(..._.flatMap(val, (seats, busKey) =>
  _.flatMap(seats, (content, seatKey) =>
    _.mapKeys(content.Bookings, (_, bookingKey) =>
      _.join([busKey, seatKey, bookingKey], '_')))
))
```

Outputs this:

```
{
  Bus-1_Seat1_21032022: {
    BookedAt: "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
    BookedBy: "Jon Doe"
  },
  Bus-1_Seat1_22032022: {
    BookedAt: "21/03/2022 9:43 PM",
    BookedBy: "James"
  },
  Bus-1_Seat2_20032022: {
    BookedAt: "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
    BookedBy: "Elijah"
  },
  Bus-1_Seat2_21032022: {
    BookedAt: "21/03/2022 3:43 PM",
    BookedBy: "Scott"
  },
  Bus-1_Seat3_22032022: {
    BookedAt: "22/03/2022 02:41 AM",
    BookedBy: "Williams"
  },
  Bus-2_Seat1_22032022: {
    BookedAt: "22/03/2022 02:39 AM",
    BookedBy: "Lucas"
  }
}
```

Step-by-step:

1. Apply `flatMap` on `val` to get the seats and key of the respective bus
2. Apply `flatMap` on the seats to get the content of each seat and its key
3. Get the bookings
4. Apply `mapKeys` on the bookings to avoid collisions on the final object. This is why we extracted the keys on each level. Assuming a valid input object, the keys will be unique.
5. Use `assign` on the result with the spread operator to merge everything into a single object

To reverse the process, something like this:

```js
const output = {}

_.forEach(_.toPairs(result), ([key, value]) => {
  const keys = _.split(key, '_')
  _.set(output, keys, value)
})
```

Comment: Can you tell how to reverse if required?

Comment: I have updated the original answer